# How do I use Impulse Responses from Waves in another convolution plugin

Tags: reverb, plug-ins, waves, convolution, convolution-reverb

I have the Waves IR plugin and it has a lot of good impulse responses but the plugin itself isnt very good and all the impulse responses come in .wir. How could I use these impulse responses on the native convolver plugin? I am using FL studio 12.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that Waves store the files in a 'wir' format is to make them proprietary, thus preventing you from using them elsewhere. You would have to reverse-engineer the 'wir' file format, extract the impulse, then move the impulse to another system before you could use it. Probably not worth the hassle.

Comment: But the Waves plugin is just terrible. I tried a default FL Studio reverb in it and it sounds way worse than the native plugin.

Comment: Also there is this but I'm not sure how to use it:  http://freeverb3vst.osdn.jp/tips/tips.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Just download'em and run wir2wav.py in the folder.

Comment: Explaining how this might be done might be more useful. Some people may not even know what a .py file is, let alone what to do with it, or which platforms it might work on.